# Converting from XML to CSV using XSLD

Tags: xml, xslt, export-to-csv

I'm wondering if you can export to CSV using XSL to a certain column. For instance in this example, some employees are missing email or phone number or department. However I want the result be that if element is missing just leave it blank.

```
 <Employees>
   <Employee>
     <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
     <EmpName>Homer Simpson</EmpName>
     <Department>IT1</Department>
     <PhNo>9111111111</PhNo>
     <Email>Homer.Simpson@gmail.com</Email>
     <Salary>99999</Salary>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
     <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
     <EmpName>John Smith</EmpName>
     <Department>IT2</Department>
     <PhNo>9222222222</PhNo>
     <Email>smith@gmail.com</Email>
     <Salary>99999</Salary>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
     <EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>
     <EmpName>Marge Simpson</EmpName>
     <Department>IT3</Department>
     <Salary>99999</Salary>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
     <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
     <EmpName>Bruce Wayne</EmpName>
     <Department>IT4</Department>
     <Email>batman@gmail.com</Email>
   </Employee>
 </Employees>


current xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'&#59;'" />
<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="Employees/Employee">
                   
             <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>        
             <xsl:value-of select="EmpName"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
             <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>  
             <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>   
             <xsl:value-of select="PhNo"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
             <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
             <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>            
               <xsl:value-of select="Salary"/>
```

Comment: You ask about CSV, but your XSLT creates rows and cells in an HTML table.

Comment: You are right! I edited!

Comment: So where is the problem? If an element is missing, you'll get a `,,` - which in CSV is a "blank field".